# Excel - formula counting the number of distinct values in column, without taking into account the indicated values from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distinct-values

I have following data in excel:

```
   Category           ID

      a            100-1234

      a            100-12345

      b            100-123456

      b            110-1234

      b            110-12345

      c            1120-92029

      c            12303-223

      c            12039-10300

      c            12930-20102
```

I would like to write a formula to calculate the number of distinct/different **IDs** of all categories except **Category** = "c" (without breakdown by category, just a total number of distinct IDs).

Comment: `except Category = "c"` means what. Only count distinct for a nd b? Then what would be your output?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a total number of distinct IDs for a and b categories

Comment: If you have Excel 365, use `FILTER` get get all qualifying records, the `UNIQUE`, then `COUNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count unique IDs excluding `c` `Total Count` use below formula-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10<>"c")/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10&""))
```

To count by category use (As per screenshot) in `E4`-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=D4)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10&""))
```

Then drag and down for next one.

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks :) And I have question. If there is one more column, named "status" with variables "yes" and "no", and I would like to calculate the same as before, but also take into account that this column should = yes, can it be done? So it would be like that: count distinct ID if category <> "c" and status = "yes"

Comment: Then use `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10<>"c")*($C$2:$C$10="Yes")/....` assuming Column C is status column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Category column is in column A, put this in your C2:

```
=IF(A2="c",0,IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)>1,0,1))
```

Drag it to the end of the list. You can then sum the column and you should have your result.